# Questionable accuracy

Tags: history, google-patents

In reference to the patent: [US3137203](https://www.google.com/patents/US3137203)

Why was the inventor's name changed when Google took custody of the document?  Joseph Brown was not the inventors name.  As the grandson of the true inventor, I can tell you this with certainty.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. Unfortunately, we have no way of modifying the documents Google provides. Google never "took custody" of this document, though, and is sometimes wrong. The USPTO (e.g. Public PAIR) is the only definitive source for information like this on United States patents and applications.